# How long is an Android Context valid?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-context

I am working on an Android App, that performs a login on a Server. Only after this login, the Network gains access to the Internet. The internet connection is lost upon 30min of inactivity. ( This is really annoying, which is why i'm trying to automate this...)

So the Idea is to create an App where the user (aka my lazy self) inputs his credentials only once, and for the rest of his life the login happens automatically in the background.

As I'm trying to use best practices to avoid Battery drain, i first of all thought of the conditions that have to be met for a login to be necesseray:

- The Phone has to be connected to a Wifi.
- wifi has a certain name (since only certain Wifis require the login)
- wifi has no Internet connection.

I figured: Use a `BroadcastReceiver`, listen for `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` and then check for necessity. I read the recent changes about Manifest registered Receivers and used a Context registered one which then starts a `JobService`. But after a while the app no longer receives these actions.

Since the [Android Developer website](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) states:

> Context-registered receivers receive broadcasts as long as their registering context is valid.

I wonder how long is the context actually valid? And is this even the right way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: As per my understanding, the context is only valid until the time the owner of the context (Application, Activity or Service) is valid. For activity suppose onDestroy is called means the context is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in the same place:

> Context-registered receivers receive broadcasts as long as their registering context is valid. For an example, if you register within an Activity context, you receive broadcasts as long as the activity is not destroyed. If you register with the Application context, you receive broadcasts as long as the app is running.

Use `JobService` and set the required network type with `setRequiredNetworkType`, don't handle network changes with a `BroadcastReceiver`. You can event set your job to be persisted across device reboots.

**EDIT:** I would create a persistant `JobService` with a required network type WIFI (which should run each time if the device connects to a WIFI network). If it runs I would check, if the device connected with the right network. If this is the case, I would then start a new periodic job with period < 30 min. This job will check, if your are still connected to the right network and do login (if needed). I would terminate the second job, if the device is not connected to the right WIFI anymore.

Comment: I haven't been able to create a Job that lived for an extended period of time. Could you direct me to an example of such a periodic Job?

Comment: How long is your "extended period of time", why do you need a long running `Service`?

Comment: Edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: @David check my answer for a solution idea.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it is not related to the Context itself. I think you do something wrong when schedule the background job. So you need to setup job as periodic.